# Unix unzip: how to batch unzip zip files in a folder and save in subfolders?

Tags: linux, unix, zip, unzip

Say if I have a folder 'images' and inside it there are 0001.zip to 9999.zip, I want to unzip all of them and save them in subfolder which has their file name, for example, 0001.zip will be unzipped and saved to /0001, 0002.zip will be unzipped and saved to /0002, I tried to do

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

but that extracts all files in current folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 for file in *.zip; do
       dir=$(basename "$file" .zip) # remove the .zip from the filename
       mkdir "$dir"
       cd "$dir" && unzip ../"$file" && rm ../"$file" # unzip and remove file if successful
       cd ..
  done
```

or, run it together on one line:

```
  for file in *.zip; do dir=$(basename "$file" .zip); mkdir "$dir"; cd "$dir"; unzip ../"$file" && rm ../"$file"; cd ..; done
```

If you need/want to keep the original .zip files, just remove the `&& rm ../"$file"` bit.

Answer (score 4):

```
for zip in *.zip
do
    unzip "$zip" -d "${zip%.zip}"
done
```