# How to unzip different compression formats in subfolders in Linux terminal

Tags: bash, unzip

I saw the following piece of code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804438/unix-unzip-how-to-batch-unzip-zip-files-in-a-folder-and-save-in-subfolders) to unzip all the .zip formats in the sub-folders into the corresponding sub-folders. My questions regarding this piece of the code are the following.

(1)Is this a bash script for a batch job?. If so can I run it as **sudo bash *filename.bat***.

(2)How to specify the parent-folder directory in the code. The parent directory contains under all the sub-folders which in turn contains the zipped(compressed) files.

(3)How to modify the code to include other compression formats such as *.rar* and *.7z*

```
 for file in *.zip; do
       dir=$(basename "$file" .zip) # remove the .zip from the filename
       mkdir "$dir"
       cd "$dir" && unzip ../"$file" && rm ../"$file" # unzip and remove file if successful
       cd ..
  done
```

Comment: This may help: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that code fragment looks like a `bash` script.  If it is named `filename.bat`, you should be able to use `sudo bash filename.bat` to run it.
2. The code assumes that the current directory is the 'parent folder' which contains all the zipped files.  You'll need to modify the code to handle sub-directories containing `.zip` files.  There are numerous ways to do that.
3. Given a requirement to handle formats other than just `.zip` files, you'd probably revise the code to use the file names it is given as arguments as the files to uncompress.

This code might work:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    extn=${base##*.}
    base=$(basename "$file" .$extn)
    mkdir -p "$dir/$base"
    (
    cd "$dir/$base"
    case $extn in
    zip)   unzip "../$base.$extn";;
    esac
    )
done
```

Now, in theory, you could extend the list of extensions in the `case` statement to include other file formats.  However, you should be aware that not all compressors also package multiple files.  Typically, you have a composite format such as `.tar.gz` or `.tar.xz` or `.tar.bz2`.  The corresponding compressors (or decompressors), simply decompress the file (losing the compression suffix) without extracting the data from the `.tar` file inside.  However, if `rar` and `7z` do behave like `zip`, then you can use:

```
    case $extn in
    (zip)   unzip "../$base.$extn";;
    (rar)   unrar "../$base.$extn";;  # Or whatever the command is
    (7z)    un7z  "../$base.$extn";;  # Or whatever the command is
    (*)     echo "$0: unrecognized extension $extn on $file" >&2;;
    esac
```

You can also reinstate the code to delete the compressed form of the file if that seems appropriate to you.